# Using 'Not equal to' with if statement in python

Tags: python, algorithm

for the following code I am getting an error which says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{'". Is something wrong in the way I compare 'i' with '{' , '}' and ','

```
c={1,2,3,4,5}
LE=[]  #to store even numbers
LO=[]   #to store odd numbers
for i in c:
    if(i != '{' or i != ',' or i != '}'):
        if(int(i)%2==0):
            LE.append(i)
        else:
            LO.append(i)
    else:
        continue

print(LE)            
print(LO)
```

Comment: let the input be {1,2,3,4,5}...still the error comes.

Comment: @Guy thats why I have used != with if condition

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], we shouldn't have to perform any input at all if that is not an actual part of the problem. Also, `LE` and `LO` are probably unnecessary as well.

Comment: `or` should be `and`

Comment: `,` is not equal to `{`, so the condition is true and you try to convert it to `int`.

Comment: @Barmar I just want that i should not be equal to '{', '} or ','....can you tell why what I have written in the if condition is wrong

Comment: Read the linked question above, it explains it all.

Comment: You can also write `if i not in "{,}":`

Comment: if(int(i)%2==0):  has a problem If you want to convert a char into its ASCII value, you need to use **ord** function. Changing to the following 

if (ord(i)%2 == 0):

may help. I think there is still some logic issue with the program.